# Side by side tables java

Tags: java

I am new and have a question that is dumbfounding me.

I'm doing a conversion table where it is side by side miles to kilometers, a similar question that was never fully answered in 3 years. now i'm only using `print(f)(ln)` format, no Jtables, nada, simple `println`.

I got the table to be side by side using for loops but ran into a problem on the output that is kicking my keester.

The output I get is repeating itself 10 times here:

```
1  1.609 | 20 32.18
2  1.609 | 21 33.789
3  1.609 | 22 35.397
```

so I used an if statment and %5 == 0 in my for loop and I got this output:

```
1  1.609 | 20 32.18
2  1.609 | 25 40.225
3  1.609 | 30 48.269
```

So now i try a break statement, and i get this:

```
1  1.609 | 20 32.18
2  3.218 | 20 32.18
3  4.768 | 20 32.18
```

I run into dead code in my second loop but it cuts off at 10 like it should in the right table but dead code in the left so I use a continue statement and get this:

```
1  1.609 | 20 32.18
2  1.609 | 25 40.225
3  1.609 | 30 48.269
```

My final correct result should be:

```
1  1.609 | 20 32.18
2  3.218 | 25 40.225
3  4.768 | 30 48.269
```

... so on till 10.

Could anybody give me a clue as to how to fix this, I dont want the answer just a little help. Thank you

Edit: how do i make my code output vertical and not horozantal so it is easier to read?

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: Welcome to the nerdy but friendly SO community. Your question needs improvement: Please add your actual program code that creates the output you so nicely discuss already. Without it, we all have a hard time guessing what you are doing.

Comment: add your code to the question please (hint-> use the edit button). And please more than the beginning of the loop. That alone does not help us much.

Comment: How do I post an answer when my phone wont let me go down a line when i hit the nextline key.

Comment: You don't post an answer. You edit your question.

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { double j = i * 1.609;  for (int k = 20; k <= 65; k++) double l = k * 0.609; System.out.println(i +  "    " + j + " | " + k + "  " + l); } } how do i line everything up like my code on here befor i post

Comment: This should be failrly easy. You need one for-loop 1<=i<=10 and an extra counter starting from 20, incrementing by 5 at the end of each loop. Not a nested loop!

Comment: Kon that i can do, and have be  doing but it still gives,me the repeated  numbers above if i could of vertically edited to make it more underatandable thats with the if statement

Comment: Calculate all of the miles to kilometers values first.  Let's say you have 20 pairs of values.  Divide the length in half to get 10.  Print the zeroth pair and the 10th pair.  Print the first pair and the 11th pair.  Repeat until you've printed the 9th pair and the 19th pair.

Comment: **EDIT YOUR QUESTION.** You can see for yourself that code in comments is completely and utterly illegible.

Comment: im sorry i screwed the code it double j is suppose to be j = i * 1.609 and double l is suppose to be l = k * 0.621. my fault on that part of the code i just caught that ej thank you so much

Comment: it was suppose to be 1 1.609 20 12.42

Comment: please do as @EJP asks/suggests. The code needs to go in the body of your **question**, not in the comments here. Code styling can be done in the provided editor. Read more about it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop, one for-loop will do the job

```
int x = 1.609;
int k = 20;
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + i*x + " | " + k + " " + k*x);
    k+=5;
}
```

Comment: the 20 has to equall 12.42 that was my fault at the top, i screwed that up it works for the left side table but not the right side  of the table my fault

Comment: Thank you guys and gals for your help, i started to figure out what i was missing. thanks, i just need to some tweaking to the code thanks.

Comment: if so, just add a second variable y = 0.621 and compute k*y

Comment: i was missing that * part in my prinln code, sorry for being confusing, first time here and was fustrated and rushed and made a few mishaps in my code when i went to type it on here.